# LINQ group by ID - Distinct by order

Tags: linq

I have data in a generic list named "Assignment" as shown in the Original table. Want to group by ID and display only one record based on US-UK-India order.

The result should transform from first table to second as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: I guess you require, unique Id and details of first entry along with it. right?

Comment: Can you describe the rule as it is unclear from the example?

Comment: What's your logic pattern behind this query . can you confirmed or edit your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
SQL like syntax.

```
from a in Assignments
group a by a.Id into gr select gr.FirstOrDefault()
```

Lambda expression:

```
Assignments
   .GroupBy (a => a.Id)
   .Select (gr => gr.FirstOrDefault ())
```

Comment: Are you sure this query will give correct output according author

Comment: i guess this is what author wants!

Comment: this query results only one row, but author is expecting result as a table.

Comment: here i am taking first record from each group based on ID, if you see ID is duplicated in the original table, author wants only the first record from the group

Comment: author wants first record for each reference.

Comment: tell me which record author will take for 3, 5, and 8?

Comment: first record for each(3,5 and 8).

Comment: this query will do the same mate, also will take all the other records(1-8) as author wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its works. I hope this is what you need.

```
var query01 = context.FirstTable
            .GroupBy(p => p.ID
            ,(ky, el) => new { ky.Value , FirstCountry = el.Select(p => Country).Take(1)});

var Result = query01
           .Join(context.FirstTable
           , ul => new
            {
           Id = ul.Value
           ,Country = ul.FirstCountry.FirstOrDefault()
           }
           , fl => new 
           {
           Id = (int)fl.ID
           , Country = fl.Country
           }
          , (ul, fl) => new { fl }).ToList();
```